# How should I use the alias_method_chain for the build method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, associations, alias

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.13 and I would like to properly use the `alias_method_chain :build, :option_name` statement since I am getting a strange error. That is, ...

... in my controller file I have:

```
class Articles::CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @articles_comment = @article.comments.build(params[:comment])
    ...
  end
end
```

... in my model file I have:

```
class Articles::Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.build_with_option_name
    ...
  end

  alias_method_chain :build, :option_name
end
```

When I run the `create` controller action I get the following error in log:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `build' for class `Articles::Comment'):
  app/models/articles/comment.rb:5:in `<class:Comment>'
```

*How should I use the `alias_method_chain` for the `build` method?* Or, maybe better, should I proceed in another way to reach what I would like to make (for example, should I overwrite the `build` method in the `Articles::Comment` model instead of using `alias_method_chain`)?

---

*Note I*: I don't know if it helps, but the `build` method refers to an association (`@article.comments`). More, I do not state the `build` method in the `Articles::Comment` model because it should be "added" / "attached" to the class by the Ruby on Rails framework itself (I think it is made through meta-programming).

*Note II*: The same error occurs when considering the `new` method instead of `build`; that is, when using `alias_method_chain :new, :option_name`.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, build is a method defined on association proxy. What you can do is to use association extensions, so in a model you can pass a block to your has_many call, which will be treated as an extension for given association_proxy:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :comments do
    alias_method_chain :build, :option_name
  end
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it seems do not work: I get an error similar to that present in the question.