# How can / should I override the `build` method for a my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, methods, overriding

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.13 and, since in my previous question ["How should I use the alias_method_chain for the build method?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163004) it seems that any solution has been found, I am considering to override the `build` method in a my model class in order to get the wanted behavior.

How can / should I override the `build` method for a my model (even when the `build` method runs for `ActiveRecord` associations as-like `@article.comments.build(...)`)?

Comment: Looks like time to break out the Rails source!

Answer (score 8):

There is a way to customize your build method , define your `build` in model relations:

```
class Article
    has_many :comments do 
        def build(*args, &block)
            #TODO your code

            super(*args, &block)
        end
    end
end
```

If you don't need default params of build method, then you can use your own.

Answer (score 1):

`build` is an alias for new in the `ActiveRecord::Relation` class.  There is this line in the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/959fb8ea651fa6638aaa7caced20d921ca2ea5c1/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L84) to make the alias:

```
alias build new
```

Here is how to override the `build` method:

```
# config/initializers/monkey_patch.rb
class ActiveRecord::Relation
  def build
    "HHHHHIIIII"
  end
end
```

If you call the `build` method on `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects, the string "HHHHHIIIII" is returned.  For example, if a Course `has_many` students, this line will return "HHHHHIIIII" in `rails console`:

```
Course.first.students.scoped.build
```

Here is how to add a method to the ActiveRecord::Relation class:

```
# config/initializers/monkey_patch.rb
class ActiveRecord::Relation
  def my_model_build
    "Happy happy, joy joy"
  end
end
```

Comment: I need to change the behavior just for *one* model, not for all models in my application.

Comment: @Backo - if you want to keep the functionality of `ActiveRecord::Relation#build`, but add a custom build for your model, just add your custom method to the `ActiveRecord::Relation` class.  I updated my answer to show how to add a method to this class.  I don't  think you can override the `ActiveRecord::Relation#build` method in some places and not in others.